# FSCalendar Swift issue with one week view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fscalendar

Trying to use the FSCalendar framework for displaying a 1 week view.[image: One week view Image]

I have currently got the one week view displaying however when I click on a day that has Data it expands the calender again to the month long view. I read on the docs to use

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        calendar.fs_height = bounds.height + 10
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

for auto resizing the view but I don't want to resize it back to the month style view I want to keep it as the week long bar at the top of my view controller. Has anyone any ideas how to keep it as one week?

[image: Image of expanded calendar view]

Comment: have you set this ? ```calendar.setScope(.week, animated: true)``` and give some hight constraint to calendar view.

Comment: Hi yes I have that set however when just that is set it just squashes the whole calendar up. The only way I found to display as one wee was to add boundingRectWillChange method, however when I use this it does collapse the calendar to one week view but when I change month and click on a date it expands the view again however when it expands there is no dates just blank space

Answer (score 2):

Create a IBOutlet for FSCalendar.

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!
```

Then, set FSCalendarScope to week.

```
calendar.scope = .week
```